# Photometric stereo: If slant and titls are known, How to find the light vector

Tags: 3d

Photometric stereo: If slant and titls are known, when finding the light vector, where should the coordinate system be? Is the upper left corner of the image the origin, or where?Thanks

Photometric stereo: If slant and titls are known, when finding the light vector, where should the coordinate system be? Is the upper left corner of the image the origin, or where?

Comment: hello, pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask